# How to avoid Fluctuation in show and hide UI controls in Xamarin forms iOS?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have layout where i am trying to hide and show 2 buttons on click of down arrow button which is in expandable list which is creating fluctuation in 2 buttons.

Tried reducing height of those 2 buttons initially and then give some height dynamically.

```
<Button x:Name="completebtn" IsVisible="{Binding TaskStatus}"
                                   AutomationId="btnComplete"
                                   Command="{Binding BindingContext.CompleteOptionClickedCommand,
                                    Source={x:Reference taskList}}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                                   Style="{StaticResource darkBlueButton}"
                                   Text="Complete"
                                   HeightRequest="50"  
                                   WidthRequest="120"></Button>
```

Actual behavior is when i expand and collapse any list item the two buttons within the list item should not fluctuate until and unless i click on down arrow button.

Comment: Do you want to  create a Custom Drawer?

Comment: No i have following hierarchy in which button is flickering :

<pre> <code>
<List>
    <List Item>
    <Layout -  click>
         <Button Visible - Click yes>
         <Button Invisible - Click no>
    </Layout>
    </List item>
</List>

Answer (score 0):

To hide and show a View in Xamarin Forms you use the `IsVisible` property which accepts a boolean and is by default set to true.

You can use it like this:

```
<Button x:Name="MyButton"...... IsVisible="false"/>
```

Then In your code, you can set it back to visible, as follows:

```
MyButton.IsVisible=true;
```

Comment: This is not i am looking for